# Java use base class for inherited native method

Tags: java, inheritance, java-native-interface

If I have

```
public class Foo {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("foo");
  }
  private native void foo();
}
```

and then

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
}
```

and in my JNI I have:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
org_mikesolomon_soq_Bar_foo
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
}
```

will the function `foo` automatically become part of `Bar`, or will the compiler expect a definition of `foo` as a native method in `Bar`?  I'm asking because I have a bunch of classes that are inheriting from a bass class and implementing a native method in the form of:

```
org_mikesolomon_soq_A_foo
org_mikesolomon_soq_B_foo
org_mikesolomon_soq_C_foo
org_mikesolomon_soq_D_foo
```

where `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` all inherit from a base class.  That would save me from writing out

```
public native void foo();
```

in each class.

Comment: If `Foo.foo()` is `private`,  it can't be inherited, so I don't see how making it `native` changes that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant protected. I did try it with protected, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native method is defined in `Foo.` Providing an implementation in `Bar` doesn't make any sense, unless there is a corresponding overriding native method declaration in the Java code of Bar.

It isn't clear what exactly you are trying to do, but this won't do anything. The native method will be ignored unless it corresponds to a Java native method declaration.

Comment: This answers my question - uprooting!